# Add data dynamically in chartNew.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, chartnew.js

Data Coming from hidden value in PHP page. I have set value in hidden field. Fetching those value in chart.html page. This html page contain `charNew.js`.

I am fetching those value as

```
var fstval= document.getElementById('fstval').value;
var sndval= document.getElementById('sndval').value;
```

In mydata var set

```
data : [fstval,0,sndval]
```

Then I have called chart.html in `iframe` in my PHP page. But I am getting null at ID. I could not understand why I am not getting the value?

Comment: Please provide your code to fix this out.

Comment: Is this possible to set value in hidden field in my PHP page and fetch  those value in my html page which I have called in iframe?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you use form tag at one page, then you could collect the value at the other intended page.

Comment: I am fetching using javascript. iframe is included on that PHP page. <input type="hidden" name="fastval" value="<?php  echo $fastval; ?>" id="fastval" />
            <input type="hidden" name="scondval" value="<?php  echo $scondval; ?>" id="scondval" />
         <iframe style="width:100%; height:350px;border:none" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/ChartNew.js-master/chart.html"></iframe>

Comment: can you please provide your code ?